# How do I prove that $(A \times B) \times C \sim A \times (B \times C)$?

Tags: logic

I am trying to prove that $(A \times B) \times C \sim A \times (B \times C)$ but I am stuck. 
First I defined a function from $f:(A \times B) \times C \rightarrow A \times (B \times C)$, so I defined this function $f((a,b),c) = (a,(b,c))$.

Now, how do I prove that it is onto?

Comment: Not that it's hard either way, but it would seem simpler to just write the inverse of $f$ and prove its an inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that :

$$\begin{array} 
f((a,b),c) = f((a',b'),c')  & \Rightarrow & (a,(b,c)) = (a',(b',c')) \\
& \Rightarrow & \left\{ \begin{array} .a = a' \\ (b,c) = (b',c') \end{array}
 \right. \\
& \Rightarrow & \left\{ \begin{array} .a = a' \\ b=b' \\c=c' \end{array} \right.\\
& \Rightarrow & \left\{ \begin{array} .(a,b) = (a',b')\\c=c' \end{array} \right.\\
& \Rightarrow &((a,b),c) = ((a',b'),c')\end{array}$$

Comment: @LiziPizi : take your time :p